# Flash html field supports span but not div?

Tags: flash

I see listed here all html tags supported
http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/Flash/Working-with-Text-and-HTML-in-Flash/5/

I can see span but not div ? Is this a mistake ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no, it's not a mistake
DIV tags are not supported

However you could just replace `<span>` with `<div>` or better yet use an html parser library

http://as3htmlparser.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thanks for the lib will be very helpfull. It's weird though flash does support span but not div !